# PowerPivot - Changed, incorrect date formatting when using data as column filter

Tags: database, excel, date, format, powerpivot

I am using the Excel Add-In PowerPivot to draw a list of values from a **Postgre-SQL** database. The first column is a date with format `(m)m/(d)d/yyyy`. Whenever I create a pivot table based on the raw data and use the date as row name, the **date** is displayed in the German format (my Excel is a German version, however regional settings are set to EN).

I need it to stay in its original format. I cannot use an additional calculated column for that. What possibilities are there to resolve this issue?

Comment: Excel 2010, I'll try as proposed on Monday!

Answer (score 0):

Ateich, after checking this, I think the issue might be more related to Excel itself rather than PowerPivot AddIn.

Try changing the *date locale* format in *Cell Format* settings, which might do the trick:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try the following. Go to Powerpivot and try change the format of the column to: data Type: Date, Format 14/03/2001. (Tab home - Fomatting : see image) And then refresh your Pivot Table. That should do the trick! Maybe not for you, but for another one with this problem.

[image: Go to Pwerpivot - Tab Home - Formatting]

[image]